# CSS: Is there a way to get same padding between sibling items

Tags: html, css, padding, border-box

I have set padding 5px between each items, but 5px + 5px become 10px between sibling items (horizontal, also vertical got 10px)

http://plnkr.co/edit/7FKBiTocHrTuwnpEqQsu?p=preview

```js
// Code goes here

angular.module('app', [])
   .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
     $scope.items = Array(10);
   })
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

*, :after, :before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.one.fifth {
  width: 20%;
}
.one.whole{
  width: 100%;
}
.pad {
  padding: 5px;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
.box {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.red.box {
  background-color: red;
}
.white.box {
  background-color: white;
}
.black.border {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body class="one whole">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <div class="red box pad center">
        <div class="white box">
          <div class="one fifth box pad" ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
            <div class="one whole black border box">TEST {{$index}}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Is there any way to get 5px exact padding or spacing between everything?

Note: I have tried + operator, but there is side effect on sixth item, because those 10 items are siblings

Comment: Why not do padding `2.5px` since 2.5+2.5=5?

Comment: because I need 5 px on left, right, top, bottom corners, but I think I got another idea to pad those back.

Comment: Add a `2.5px` padding / margin to the container too, that will give you a `5px` gap on left right top and bottom!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to change the value of `.pad` to `2.5px` and its working as you expected

**Edit**: Added `padding` for `.white.box` and now all the sides having consistent padding

```js
// Code goes here

angular.module('app', [])
   .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
     $scope.items = Array(10);
   })
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

*, :after, :before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.one.fifth {
  width: 20%;
}
.one.whole{
  width: 100%;
}
.pad {
  padding: 2.5px; / * changed this value to 2.5px and its working */
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
.box {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.red.box {
  background-color: red;
}
.white.box {
  background-color: white;
 padding:3px 2px 2px 2px;
}
.black.border {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body class="one whole">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <div class="red box pad center">
        <div class="white box">
          <div class="one fifth box pad" ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
            <div class="one whole black border box">TEST {{$index}}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps you !!

Comment: nice try but that also make 2.5px on left, right, top, bottom borders, i need 5px there too. but I think I now get another idea. to pad those back. thank you xD

Comment: actually, it was no needed to add custom padding to .white.box, but changing to .white.box to .white.box.pad works.

Comment: ok.. didnt created new class, just used whatever you used already :)

Comment: I meant `<div class="white box">` to `<div class="white box pad">`, no new class.

Answer (score 3):

Why can't you just use the `nth-child` CSS selector? Give everything besides the first element a `padding-right` of `5px`, and for the first element give it a `padding-left` of `5px` too. Easiest solution, no?

Link to docs: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: I can't use nth-child, because, those 5 columns will be 4 columns or 3 columns in narrower screens, that I didn't mention in the post.

Comment: @YOU - don't use padding from the elements themselves. Create padding on the containing element. That way, you don't have to style the 1st element on each line. I think you're overthinking the problem.

Comment: yes, you're right. I was over thinking the problem. almost wrote complex adjusting with javascript. xD